# How does Wave Launcher on Android respond to Gesture Events

Tags: android

How does Wave Launcher on Android[1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobilemerit.wavelauncher) respond to Gesture Events without replacing the default Launcher App?

The interesting permissions are "display system-level alerts" which I assume they use to draw the launcher and "automatically start at boot" which I assume is a service? that they use to listen for the gestures?

Are they using a service to detect Gestures and if so how do you do that? Or are they just creating a transparent window that is doing the detection?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobilemerit.wavelauncher